# Adding info to day numbers in jquery datepicker calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I want to add additional information to the calendar in the jquery datepicker. Currently the calendar comes up showing the month with the days listed in the view of a calendar. What I want to do is add a number in parenthesis next to the day number. I am writing a form for a scheduler and I want to show the user how many events are already scheduled for that day using the calendar.

I don't have sufficient privileges to add pictures to this post so I will try my best to demonstrate what I am looking for below.

Regular Datepicker calendar:

```
Su   M   T   W   TH  F   Sa
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 8   9  10  11   12  13  14
```

What I am looking for:

```
  Su     M      T      W      TH     F      Sa
 1(2)   2(1)   3(1)   4(1)   5(1)   6(1)   7(8)
 9(1)   10(2)  11(5)  12(4)  13(3)  14(6)  15(2)

**the numbers in parenthesis () are the number of appointments
  already scheduled for that day.**
```

I get the required information to be entered into the parenthesis from a mySQL query. It returns the date and the count. I can format the date to match anything your solution requires.

I had the thought of creating variables that are named after the specific date with the definition being the count (ex. var 2012-1-30 = 1, var 2012-1-31 = 4). Then I would somehow have the datepicker function add the definition when the day matched the variable date that I created. I'm not sure if there would be a way to add this to the datepicker function.

Another solution which I tried and could not get to work was to edit the datepicker function to add a class to each day so that I could select each day with jquery. For example Jan 30, 2012 had a class that looked like [class="date_2012-1-30"]. I could manually select and edit the days this way using the class (that is how I edited the second picture), but I could not get the datepicker to use this info. I tried the beforeshow event in datepicker thinking that I could have the calendar edit the text in the matching classes before it is shown, but that did not work.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to accomplish what I am looking for. Again, I am trying to add a number in parenthesis after the day number in the calendar in the jquery datepicker.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to any day by setting its `beforeShowDay` event,

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [true, 'date_' + date.getTime()];
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Where dateday is a class to be added to the date and date is the day that the class is added to.